# Colour code week 1 and week 2 per month

Tags: solspace-calendar

Is there a way to apply a class (so the week can be coloured) to week A and week A using Solspace Calendar as per the screengrab? Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users in the past have used categories for differentiating events. Depending on the category the event is associated with, a different class would be used in the calendar table cell. A lot depends on your template code, but the `{categories}{/categories}` tag pair should be useable.

There might be other strategies, such as using a custom field (eg. select field) to do something similar.